# How to design for higher scalability, in SQL Server databases that need set operations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, scale

Imagine a movie application that reommends the next movie to users based on this very simple algorithm:

- Movie should be new to user
- User has not marked the movie as "not interested"

This is a simple design of SQL Server's database:

```
Movies:
    Id bigint
    Name nvarchar(100)

SeenMovies:
    Id bigint
    UserId bigint
    MovieId bigint

NotInterestedFlags:
    Id bigint
    UserId bigint
    MovieId bigint
```

To get the next movie we run this query:

```
select top 1 *
from Movies 
where Id not in 
(
    select MovieId 
    from SeenMovies 
    where UserId = 89283
)
and Id not in 
(
    select MovieId 
    from NotInterestedFlags
    where UserId = 89283
)
```

This design is getting slower and slower by more usage of the application and more data.
So with an imaginary database with 100K movies and over 10 million customers, how to change this design to make it scale horizontally?

Comment: Do you have indexes (clustered or covering) on UserID?

Comment: @DanGuzman, AMAIK any indexing is not a solution for **horizontal scaling**. Correct me if I'm wrong. But I think indexing won't help OP.

Comment: Try changing your `not in` statements to `not exists`

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, agreed indexing is not by itself a solution for horizontal scaling. It may be the solution for the root cause of the performance problems, though.

Comment: Why do you need the Id column in the SeenMovies and NotInterestedMovies? Also, 
I would suggest A single User/Movie table with a tinyint column that will tell you why that combination of user and movie is in that table - i.e 1 - seen, 2 - not interested (If you will ever want to include more reasons, tinyInt can hold values between 0-255, so nothing in the structure needs to change)

Comment: @ZoharPeled that makes no difference in sharding redesign. The original request is about sharding design for set operations.

Comment: It just seems like a better design to me. The current design use multiple tables that has (at least in this perspective) the same meaning. It's almost like creating different tables for comedy and drama. What if a month from now a new reason not to select movies will be introduced to the system? This type of scaling should also be considered.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, your argument is totally valid. The overall schema can be improved. But to follow SoC (separation of concerns) your suggestion is not valid IN THIS CONTEXT. I mean, even a poorly designed database might also be the subject of sharding.

Comment: Well, I guess we will have to disagree.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't do horizontal scaling; it specializes in vertical scaling. This has little to do with your design. Of course you can implement some form of sharding yourself, but you'll be fighting against the nature of the RDBMS. There are many ways this design could be sped up on a single vertically scaling instance (10M users and 100K movies form maybe 1B preferences, which isn't even that big), but if your goal is horizontal scaling, consider something other than SQL Server (at least for the specific goal of storing movie preferences).

Comment: You could separate out the writing / updating of data from the reading of data using SQL Server Always On Availability groups and read only secondaries. Alternatively you could consider a table partitioning scheme to move reads / writes to different disks or you could go the whole hog and shard the database based upon the UserId or a hash of the userId.

Answer (score 1):

The following is something like the code I would recommend.

I assume SeenMovies and NotInterestedFlags are clustered, or at the very least indexed, on UserId. And that Movies is clustered on MovieId. If not, adding such indexes will be the first place to start.

I certainly don't see any reason why there should be poor performance *per individual query* with the sort of volumes you're talking about, because once we have confined the query to a specific user, both SeenMovies and NotInterestedFlags should only have at most a few thousand rows each for that user.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Movies.*

FROM
    Users

CROSS JOIN
    Movies

WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM SeenMovies
        WHERE 
            SeenMovies.UserId = Users.Id
            AND
            SeenMovies.MovieId = Movies.Id 
    )
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM NotInterestedFlags
        WHERE 
            NotInterestedFlags.UserId = Users.Id
            AND
            NotInterestedFlags.MovieId = Movies.Id 
    )
    AND
    Users.Id = 89283
```

If this still performs poorly even with appropriate indexes, I could only imagine that first maybe first `UNION`ing the MovieId entries in the SeenMovies and NotInterestedFlags for that UserId, and then `EXCEPT`ing these against Movies, might provide better performance.

On the other hand, if the problem is that the overall performance of the system is degrading under the load of many users, you might have to look at pre-preparing a list for every user of un-seen and un-blacklisted movies, from which you query the `TOP 1`.

And then, when a user watches a movie or blacklists it (or a new movie is added), this new table is modified at the same time as the separate SeenMovies and NotInterestedFlags tables.

Again, if that doesn't help performance enough, then you'd have to look at implementing a daily batch job, maybe, that pre-prepares a list of say 10 unseen and non-blacklisted movies per user, and this table is then queried and offered to the user one-at-a-time.

I think frankly though, if there is a prospect of you having 10 million users, you could probably afford an expert to write the code or evaluate the existing system.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cache for each user with "shortlisted" movies. An indexed view might work well for that. The point is not to run the full query each time a user wants to see the list but occasionally update the shortlist. Those individual lists together with User flags tables can be scaled horizontally by some user attribute. User Location might be a good choice here for cloud migration in the future.

Comment: A Left Anti Semi Join is likely to be faster than a left join i.e. using NOT EXISTS see http://sqlity.net/en/1360/a-join-a-day-the-left-anti-semi-join/

Comment: Thanks @SteveFord. I'll test it (after all, the article is 5 years old). But in any case, it's much better than `not in`.

Comment: @Y.B. 10M rows is *not* a lot of data. There's no point in investigating sharding when simply adding the *correct* indexes or fixing the query could result in improvements of orders of magnitud *and* stable performance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, the question was how to scale, not how to index. No indexes would help when a few thousand customers simultaneously look up their next favorite movie.

Comment: @Y.B. you don't need to scale if you *fix* the performance problems. You *won't* scale if you just throw money at the problem without fixing the glaring problems. You'll only make the vendor or cloud provider happy. At best, you *may* see an initial improvement but perfromance will keep degrading at the same rate. Worst case, performance will be far worse if eg you use the wrong type of partitioning or don't replicate the movies table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree that optimizing indexes might help in some cases. I would also investigate possible storage system bottlenecks. The question was "how to ... make it scale horizontally?" I assume other options has been exhausted.

Comment: For *only* 10M rows and such a simple query? There's no basis for that assumption. And not "some cases" unless you work in the TB range. Not when a small server has 32/64 GB RAM and SSDs. 10M rows can probably fit in RAM. 100K rows definitely do

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's always the simplest queries that are bringing systems to their knees. Think 10k users running their 10k simple queries every second. Like DoS attack, only legitimate.